# Reconnecting to a console output after system restart

Tags: linux, tmux, gnu-screen

For a running script on a Linux VM with a regular console output: If I disconnect from the VM the output window disappears. If I restart the VM, the script is still running but how do I get back to the output-screen?

Comment: elaborate on how you connect/disconnect from the VM. If you connect to it via SSH, and that session disconnects, you can't get the output. If you connect to the screen of the VM using the software that runs the VM, you can get the output.

Comment: its a aws ec2 vm and i'm connected to it via SSH. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I used to do that a lot, and redirect output to a file, which I could read during/after the command executes.

Comment: Yeah I did that now as well! I just noticed, that if a disconnect with the SSH-connection my Python-Script terminats as well. Is there any way, so that the script will keep on running?

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution: use GNU screen, or an alternative like tmux to run your scripts in a persistent session. Thus, if you accidentally disconnect from your SSH session (or must shut down your computer), you can still reattach to the screen session later.

Tutorial: [Using GNU Screen to Manage Persistent Terminal Sessions](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/ssh/using-gnu-screen-to-manage-persistent-terminal-sessions/)

Another great feature is that screen can also log the console output to a file. I use it all the time for cron jobs or other unattended tasks. I also use screen for updates (using yum, dnf or whatever), because updates can take a lot of time, and sometimes may even have to restart the network service, which would terminate your SSH session.